# Where can I find tag of a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to Fragments and I want to call a Fragment's method from another Activity

I tried making Instance of Class... but it did bot work

How can i do that??
on most forums it is said use findFragmentByID or Tag
But where can i find the Tag of my Fragment????

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm new to Fragments as well, but I don't think I understand your question. Fragments are typically hosted by activities.  There are ways for fragments between different activities to send messages and invoke code between each other, but I'd like to know, "what are you really trying to do" to elaborate.  (hint: show us the code and error you are getting)

Answer (score 1):

```
   mgr.findFragmentByTag("mytag");
```

Finds a fragment that was identified by the given tag either when inflated from XML or as supplied when added in a transaction.

You can set the tag when you put the fragment in the container.  Such as the following:

```
   mgr.beginTransaction().replace(container, myfragment, "mytag").commit();
```

There is a getTag() method inside fragment as well, however no set method (that I can see).  This is probably because fragment tags are designed to be set either in the xml, which your other answer describes how to set, or as part of a fragment transaction as I showed above.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all,
Actually, My fragment leaded to several activities
(means different activities within a fragment );
and I needed to access a method from that Fragment
so, I tried making an instance of it... using the methods I stated, but could nt ;
so I made method static and called by the Fragment Identifier.